# GAE app debugging slow in Eclipse Indigo Java EE IDE

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

Iam using Eclipse Indigo(Java EE IDE) & have gwt plugin installed on it. When I debug my GAE application it takes a lot of time to start. 
(My current config is 1gb ram,intel dual core, windows 7 os. Also appengine.google.com is disabled by my proxy server.). My plugins are gwt 2.4.0 & appengine SDK 1.6.0.              Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: How large is this "lot of time"?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove all the break points and run it again.

Also, SDK 1.6.0 is known to have that bug. Please, upgrade.

Comment: Same happened with GWT2.5.1 and SDK 1.8.5, Had around 10 "not relevant" breakpoints at rarely used methods and removed them. This speeded up my startup time from 3minutes to 15s. Thanks for the hint!